# if a 32-bit OS running on dual core 64-bit CPU, are both core performance's are lower?

Tags: windows-7, 32bit-64bit

if a 32-bit OS running on dual core 64-bit CPU, are both core performance's are lower?

what is exactly happening inside CPU?

Are the 2 cores still working together, and slower than if equipped with 64-bit OS?

I am using a Win 7 32-bit Professional on Intel P6200.

Thanks

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

The major advantage of 64-bit CPUs is their ability to address more memory.  It generally won't affect speed.  An exception might be where a given program can run faster with more RAM, and you actually have that much RAM (more than 4GB on Windows).  (And, of course, the program must be a 64 bit application.)

The processors are working together in exactly the same way.  They just have smaller address spaces with the 32 bit OS.

Answer (score 1):

From user perspective a 64-bit operating system mostly just allows you to run 64-bit applications. And why would you do that?

If your application has a dedicated 64-bit version, and it is heavy on numerical calculations, which were optimized to use capabilities of x64 platform (mostly more general-purpose registers), or needs a lot of RAM (more than 2GB) at once, then there are chances it will work faster.

Otherwise, most probably it will work at the same speed as 32-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

It makes very little difference but my experience is that a 64 bit OS runs some 32 bit apps very slightly better than a 32 bit OS. But it's marginal at best.